# Facebook Activity Feed not working

Tags: facebook

I have used facebook activity feed plugin in my applications,it was worked fine for the past few weeks, now its not working in the website.

I have tested it by my website url in the following facebook url

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/ it does not bring out the feeds as it before.

Can anyone please suggest me whats the problem happening in Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  Instead of

```
< fb:activity site="http://example.com" width="180" height="500" header="true" recommendations="false">
```

use this:

```
< fb:activity site="example.com" width="180" height="500" header="true" recommendations="false">
```

In short: Replacing URL with domain name in the site property.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the old iFrame is it working, but the new code series is not.

Change the part that I've put in bold to show your correct FB URL and it should test out just fine. Until the other, newer code is active, I'd skip it.

Comment: If you use the old iFrame is it working, but the new code series is not.

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2F**www.facebook.com/yourURL**&width=700&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color=ffffff&stream=true&header=false&height=350" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:700px; height:350px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Change the part that I've put in bold to show your correct FB URL and it should test out just fine. Until the other, newer code is active, I'd skip it. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Some times a facebook social plugin will not work properly if the fanpage permissions aren't adjusted to allow "Anyone 13+"

Checkout the image on this blog post, just click to zoom and follow the instructions it will fix this facebook social plugin problem in many instances: http://www.profromgo.com/facebook-social-plugin-working-logged-users

Answer (score 0):

i also am having issues with the FB activity displaying properly. if you use IPBs built-in activity feed, and default social sharing settings, it doesn't display. you have to use the iframe code on a custom made block. its how i fixed it. ipb3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this answer as when I Google I can to this post (even though it is two years old).

Essentially you can show the activity feed by using the Like Box as the activity feed is, by reading this and other forums a nightmare to try to work. Whereas the below takes seconds.

Turns out if you go to the like box page you can do it this way, much easier...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

then tick 'show posts' and that is it.