# Facebook Activity Feed with

Tags: vb.net, facebook

I have searched around for what I thought was going to be an easy item on my agenda. I am looking to add a Facebook activity to

Steps I have tried:

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity/ 
Put in the facebook URL that I want to display on my website (www.facebook.com/companysfacebookurltag) when that did not work I tried their homepage www.company.com and www.company.com/default.aspx (with and without the http)

I created an App and copied that ID in from https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ (I assume that is how I get an app ID???) and taken this out of Sandbox mode.

The code in the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity/ shows the words "recent activity" and have 6,082,608 people recommending whereas I think ours is actually 28 and nothing displays.

Surly it should not be complex, the twitter feed took minutes....

I have read [Facebook Activity Feed not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727015/facebook-activity-feed-not-working) for example but now am quite frankly stumped!

I swear this was easy when I did it years ago for another company (I mean like four plus years ago) has it changed alot?

Thank you in advance, apologies for lack of code but Facebook generates it at the end so really it is a 'how to' rather than coding issue (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you go to the like box page you can do it this way, much easier...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

then tick 'show posts' and that is it.